# SELECT rows based on ids in a view

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query :

```
SELECT `company_id`, `product_id`, `expiresAt`, `createdAt`, `createdBy`, `disabledAt`
FROM subscription
WHERE `disabledAt` IS NULL AND `company_id` IN(16867, 19164)
ORDER BY `createdAt` DESC;
```

Which produces this:

```
company_id  product_id  expiresAt   createdAt       createdBy   disabledAt  
19164   3   2023-05-02  2022-06-09 12:41:37 1   NULL    
19164   3   2022-05-02  2022-06-09 12:40:47 1   NULL    
16867   3   2023-05-31  2022-05-20 08:18:36 1   NULL    
16867   3   2023-05-31  2022-05-20 08:18:08 1   NULL    
16867   3   2022-05-31  2022-05-12 14:49:51 1   NULL    
16867   3   2022-05-26  2021-05-26 07:20:52 1   NULL
```

I want to select 1st instance on each company_id. For example:

`19164   3   2023-05-02  2022-06-09 12:41:37 1    NULL`

`16867   3   2023-05-31  2022-05-20 08:18:36 1    NULL`

How can I achieve this? Thanks

EDIT:

Applying group by gives wrong result:

```
SELECT `company_id`, `product_id`, `expiresAt`, `createdAt`, `createdBy`, `disabledAt`
FROM subscription
WHERE `disabledAt` IS NULL AND `company_id` IN(16867, 19164)
GROUP BY `company_id`
ORDER BY `createdAt` DESC;
```

Result:

```
company_id  product_id  expiresAt   createdAt       createdBy   disabledAt  
19164   3   2022-05-02  2022-06-09 12:40:47 1   NULL    
16867   3   2022-05-26  2021-05-26 07:20:52 1   NULL
```

**MYSQL SERVER VERSION: 5.7.39**

Comment: 5.7.39, No there is no unique columns

Comment: Yes but not really, the table is ordered as DESC by createdAt, and the correct is still what I require.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ROW_NUMBER` and `PARTITION BY` you can achieve this. Try below

```
select * from
(
SELECT company_id, 
product_id, 
expiresAt, 
createdAt, 
createdBy, 
disabledAt,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY company_id ORDER BY createdAt desc) AS rownumber
FROM subscription
WHERE disabledAt IS NULL AND company_id IN(16867, 19164)
) t where rownumber=1
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think the syntax is incorrect. I am getting syntax error for this query. Can you please double check ? Thanks

I think MYSQL server version doesn't support rownumber

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
`company_id`,
`product_id`, 
`expiresAt`,
`createdAt`, 
`createdBy`, 
`disabledAt`
FROM subscription
WHERE `disabledAt` IS NULL AND `company_id` IN(16867, 19164)
GROUP BY company_id
ORDER BY `createdAt` DESC;
```

Comment: It gives wrong result

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality
Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some
guidelines for How do [I write a good
answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are
**not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted
because they are less useful to a community of learners. Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary table with same columns but the `company_id` is unique.

```
CREATE TABLE `subscription_temp` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `expiresAt` date NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `createdBy` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `disabledAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_A3C664D3979B1AD6` (`company_id`),
  KEY `IDX_A3C664D34584665A` (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1024 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Then we can insert the data into it like:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO subscription_temp (`company_id`, `product_id`, `expiresAt`, `createdAt`, `createdBy`, `disabledAt`)
SELECT `company_id`, `product_id`, `expiresAt`, `createdAt`, `createdBy`, `disabledAt`
FROM subscription
WHERE `disabledAt` IS NULL AND `company_id` IN(SELECT DISTINCT `company_id` FROM subscription)
ORDER BY `createdAt` DESC;
```

With this it will only keep the first occurrence of row and ignore the rest hence having a data with desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just missing the min function in the group by. This will pick the first row by the createdAt.

```sql
SELECT `company_id`, `product_id`, `expiresAt`, min(`createdAt`), `createdBy`, `disabledAt`
FROM subscription
WHERE `disabledAt` IS NULL AND `company_id` IN(16867, 19164)
GROUP BY `company_id`
ORDER BY min(`createdAt`) DESC;
```